# How to create a dataTable like component but with columns insertion programmatically?

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I have to display a two dimensional table with a great number of columns and rows and the two dimensions are not fixed. Using JSF2 dataTable there is the constraint that the number of colums cannot be dynamic: each coloumn must have the proper jsf tag . 
Is there a way to insert the columns programmatically as for the rows in the dataTable?
Also panelGrid does not suit because you have to specify and write all the tags by hand.
I prefer not to use javascript to create such a component, I would like to exploit JSF2 as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [standard JSF component set](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) does not have such a component where it would be logically named `<h:columns>`. There exist however 3rd party component libraries which have such a component. For example, [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc.html) with [`<t:columns>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_columns.html) and [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) with [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf). The Tomahawk components doesn't generate any additional look'n'feel, so this is perfect if you want full control over CSS yourself. The PrimeFaces one generates a customizeable look'n'feel with help of [CSS themeroller framework](http://primefaces.org/themes.html), so this is perfect if you want to utilize themeroller to manage look'n'feel.

Here's an example of how you could use Tomahawk's `<t:columns>`, copied and slightly changed from its [tag documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_columns.html):

```
<t:dataTable value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
    <t:columns value="#{bean.columns}" var="column">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.name}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row[column.name]}"/>
    </t:columns>
</t:dataTable>
```